# How to TrimEnd from a List

Tags: c#, list

I am trying to remove the ? from the end of a word in a List using `TrimEnd`, If there is a better way than `TrimEnd` I'll take it.

I've tried `Trim` and `Remove`. The List is `.Split(' ')` from a string that end with the "?" concatenated to the last word.

```
    public static List<String> CleanThing(List<string> dirtyList)
    {
        List<string> cleanList = new List<string>(); 
       // cleanList = 
       /*  dirtyList.ForEach(delegate(string e)
       e = e.TrimEnd('?')
       =*/
        Console.WriteLine("\nThe # of Removals is: " + dirtyList.RemoveAll(x => x == "What" || x == "?" || x == "is") + "\n");

        dirtyList.ForEach(delegate(string e){               
        e = e.TrimEnd('?');
        Console.WriteLine(e);
        });

        cleanList = dirtyList;

        return cleanList;
    }
}
```

The returned List has the "two?" however `Console.WriteLine(e)` displays "two"

Comment: This does nothing: `delegate(string e) e = e.TrimEnd('?')`. The parameter, `e`, is essentially a local variable that goes away, vanishes, and disappears after the delegate executes. You were assigning the trimmed value to a variable that got thrown away immediately.

Answer (score 1):

You're reassigning the e Variable, which will create a new object, `e = e.TrimEnd('?')`, You will not update the one in list because its still pointing to the old reference,

Instead just select what you want into your clean list:

```
cleanList = dirtyList.Select(x => x.TrimEnd('?')).ToList()
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with immutability of strings. The code already assigns the altered string back to `e`. This is about the `e` variable used in the delegate not being the same as a reference to `List[index]`.

Answer (score 1):

I see a couple of LINQ solutions posted here.

If you fancied a non-LINQ solution, one approach could be using a `for` loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dirtyList.Count; i++) {
    dirtyList[i] = dirtyList[i].TrimEnd('?');
}
```

This moves through each element in the `List`, replacing the existing value with the `TrimEnd`'d one.

Alternatively, if you want to add the cleaned value directly to `cleanList`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dirtyList.Count; i++) {
    cleanList.Add(dirtyList[i].TrimEnd('?'));
}
```

If adding directly to `cleanList`, you could also use `foreach`:

```
foreach (string item in dirtyList) {
    cleanList.Add(item.TrimEnd('?'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
trimed = mylist.Select(s => s.TrimEnd('.')).ToList()
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.